# Breadth First Search does not return the correct ordering for nodes

Tags: python, list, tree, traversal

I have implemented a tree that looks like this :

```
               1

    2          3          4

 5     6               7      8
```

I want to print it Breadth wise. This is my code :

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.children = []


class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node()

    def build(self):
        self.root.data = 1
        self.root.children.append(Node())
        self.root.children.append(Node())
        self.root.children.append(Node())
        self.root.children[0].data = 2
        self.root.children[1].data = 3
        self.root.children[2].data = 4

        self.root.children[0].children.append(Node())
        self.root.children[0].children.append(Node())

        self.root.children[2].children.append(Node())
        self.root.children[2].children.append(Node())

        self.root.children[0].children[0].data = 5
        self.root.children[0].children[1].data = 6

        self.root.children[2].children[0].data = 7
        self.root.children[2].children[1].data = 8
        return


    def traverseBF(self, node):
        li = []
        trav = []
        li.append(node)
        while len(li) != 0:
            for x in li:
                trav.append(x.data)
                for z in x.children:
                    li.append(z)
                # map(lambda z: li.append(z), x.children)
                li.remove(x)
        print(trav)



t = Tree()
t.build()
t.traverseBF(t.root)
```

The Ouput is : [1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 8]

My Questions are :

1. Why is 3 getting inserted in trav[] before 2, even though in root.children the order is [2,3,4]
2. Why does the commented out map function does not give the same results as the for loop above it ?

Comment: Using append inside a loop or using map with side effects are both very unpythonic ways of extending a list. Check out the `list.extend()` method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with how you manage your queue. Use a single `while` loop which checks for the length of the list. Inside the while, pop the first node, then extend the queue with the popped node's children. Your function should look like this:

```
def traverseBF(self, node):
    li = []
    trav = []
    li.append(node)
    while len(li) != 0:
        x = li.pop(0)          # pop the first item
        li.extend(x.children)  # extend the queue with children
        trav.append(x.data)
    print(trav)
```

With this, `t.traverseBF(t.root)` prints `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`.

---

Here's a "cleaner" version of your code. I like generators so I turned this into a generator that returns the node values in BFS order one by one:

```
def bfs(node):
    q = [node]
    while q:
        n = q.pop(0)
        q.extend(n.children)
        yield n.data

[*bfs(t.root)]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Why doesn't the while loop exit at x = li.pop(0) ? As the root is the only node in the first iteration and so len(li) becomes 0 after popping.

Comment: @TyrangeDenhops the loop condition is checked for the first time before the loop is entered (it passes since the queue has length 1). The next time the loop condition is checked again is after the last statement of the previous iteration was run (i.e., the line that extends the queue - so it passes since its length is 3), so your assumption is incorrect.

Comment: Ohh. Gosh I'm embarassed I didn't know that being a CSE student. I used to think the loop exits as soon as the condition becomes true. But just in case, what would I have to do if I wanted that someday? Check condition at every line?

Comment: Btw I'm accepting your first answer. Thanks. The second one is beyond my scope as I haven't learnt generators yet. Do you think it would be helpful if I learnt those advanced concepts? How often do you use them?

Comment: @TyrangeDenhops If you're writing something like that you're likely doing it wrong. Don't sweat it. Take your time and follow the pace your teacher sets for you. Eventually when you learn to use this syntax it'll become natural.